# How do I exit out of an entire program through a function?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm a noob to python and I wanted to make a "digital signboard". I only have "A" and "B" right now.
I don't know how to exit out of the program completely using sys.exit(). I guess it only exits out of the function and then continues on to the next line of code to ask for the next letter. I want it to exit the program entirely once "end" is inputted but still have the letters displayed before it exits.

```
import time, sys

def getLetter(letter):
    while True:
        if letter =='A'or letter=='a':
            print('<A>')
            return
            break
    
        elif letter =='B'or letter=='b':
            print('<B>')
            return
            break
        elif letter == 'space':
            print('')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('')
            time.sleep(0.1)
        elif letter == 'end':
            sys.exit('Signboard Terminated')

#instructions
print('Welcome to  virtual signboard\n')
time.sleep(0.5)
print('Instructions:')
time.sleep(0.5)
print('Enter each character individually (max: 10 characters).')
time.sleep(0.5)
print('To enter a space, type "space"')
time.sleep(0.5)
print('To finish, type "end"')

print('Enter first character:')
firstLetter=input()
time.sleep(0.2)
print('\nEnter second character:')
secondLetter=input()
time.sleep(0.2)
print('\nEnter third character:')
thirdLetter=input()
time.sleep(0.2)

#getting output
output=getLetter(firstLetter)
output=getLetter(secondLetter)
output=getLetter(thirdLetter)
```

So ideally this would happen:
Enter first character:
A

Enter second character:
end

and the whole program would stop there without asking for the second and third character but display A only

Comment: It exits properly when you input `a`, then `b`, then `exit`. And yes, the very purpose of `sys.exit` is to terminate the entire program.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. i was wondering if for example, I inputted A and immediately wanted to exit without having to input the next letter, how would I get around to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The `sys.exit` indeed is used to terminate the entire program. In your case the flow of the program is probably invalid. Please, compare to the code below and decide which workflow should your application apply to.

```
import sys

def getLetter(letter):
    if letter =='A'or letter=='a':
        print('<A>')
    elif letter =='B'or letter=='b':
        print('<B>')
    elif letter == 'space':
        print('<space>')
    elif letter == 'end':
        sys.exit('Signboard Terminated')
    else:
        print("<Other number>")

#instructions
print('Welcome to  virtual signboard\n')
print('Instructions:')
print('Enter each character individually (max: 10 characters).')
print('To enter a space, type "space"')
print('To finish, type "end"')

while True:
    print('Enter character:')
    character = input()
    #getting output
    getLetter(character)
```

Comment: BTW, `getLetter` automatically returns `None`, so `output` will always be `None`

Comment: hey thanks for the answer! it exits out of the program but it doesnt display <A> and <B> together.

Ideally it should be:
Enter character: 
A
Enter character:
B
Enter character:
end

<A>
<B>

Comment: @AccioPotter then you should change an application to do whatever you like and however you like. This example displays the usage of the `sys.exit` following the question in the title

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to import `sys` just for exitting the program. use `exit('Signboard Terminated')` to terminate with the message `Signboard Terminated`. If i'm correct the code seems fine, because you are taking character inputs first, and then passing it into the function to print the signboard. If you need to end the program when the user types `end` you will have to check each user inputs, that if he typed the word `end` before calling the getLetter() function.

i.e.

```
def exitFun(letter):
    if letter.lower() == "end":
        exit('terminated')

print('Enter first character:')
firstLetter=input()
exitFun(firstLetter)
time.sleep(0.2)
print('\nEnter second character:')
secondLetter=input()
exitFun(secondLetter)
time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! yep, so the user inputs everything first and signboard is printed later.  I tried your code out and it works to end the program completely but it doesn't show the previous characters before "end".